# How to setScale in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, webkit, android-webview

I need to set the scale of a WebView to a given value. By the way I'm using

```
if (targetScale<wv.getScale){
    while (wv.getScale>targetScale){
         wb.zoomIn();
    }
} else {
    while (wv.getScale<targetScale){
         wb.zoomOut();
    }
}
```

But it is a very bad method (since the bucle can be infinite if the target scale is very big or small). How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You can set `setInitialScale(targetScale)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately so far there is no setscale method available in android webiview. setInitialScale work befor the loading of webview. But at run time its not working. But by using setScalX and setScalY you get some scaling result along horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

For complete zoomout at run time, here is a workaround;

```
            while(viewMap.zoomOut());
```